# free() function does not clear well my stack

Tags: c, struct, stack, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Sorry if my code and also English are a bit sketchy.

I am currently trying to print and deallocate the space in which my stack structs were stored with a function which the prototype is `void printStack(struct cell *p)`. It calls also another function which is basically a pop function for stacks (once picked the first element stored in it, the function returns it) (`struct cell *pop(struct cell **p)`).

The body of both functions are here down below:

```
struct cell *pop(struct cell **p) {

    struct cell *temp;
    if(*p == NULL)
        return *p;
    else {
        temp = *p;
        *p = (*p)->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
}

void printStack(struct cell *p){

    struct  cell *popped;
    if(p == NULL) {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
    } else {
        while(p != NULL) {
            popped = pop(&p);
            if(popped != NULL) {
                printf("Value popped: %d\n", popped->elem);
                free(popped);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The struct I have implemented is this one:

```
struct cell {
    int elem;
    struct cell *next;
};
```

The problem, now, is that the function clears everything except for the last element which keeps stored into the heap.

What have I done that brings to this behaviour?

Comment: FYI, The original pointer passed to `printStack` (the caller of which you don't show here for mysterious reasons), is by-value. That caller's pointer will not change, and be left dangling to the original now-freed stack head. An actual [mcve] , including the mechanism you're using for detecting the "last element which keeps stored into the heap" , would be highly beneficial to your question quality, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the pointer to the top node by reference.

```
void printStack( struct cell **p){
    struct  cell *popped;
    if ( *p == NULL ) {
        printf("The stack is empty\n");
    } else {
        while ( *p != NULL ) {
            popped = pop( p );
            if(popped != NULL) {
                printf("Value popped: %d\n", popped->elem);
                free(popped);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if the pointer to the top node has for example the name `p` then the function is called like

```
printStack( &p );
```

Otherwise the original pointer passed as an argument will not be changed because the function deals with a copy of its value.

So the effect of passing by value is that the data member `next` of the original pointer to the top node will be set to `NULL` due to this statement

```
temp->next = NULL;
```

within the function `pop` while the original pointer itself will store the same value that it had before calling the function `printStack`.

Take into account that you could rewrite the while loop within the function the following way

```
        while ( ( popped = pop( p ) ) != NULL ) {
            printf("Value popped: %d\n", popped->elem);
            free(popped);
        }
```